# How do I deploy gwtp samples from https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples

Tags: tomcat, gwt, gwtp

I downloaded the samples from https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples and I run the gwtp-sample-basic application via Run As > Maven build with Maven goals clean gwt:run. It opens the super development mode console from which I can "open in default browser" the application. Now however I would like to deploy the application to a Tomcat 8 server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn clean package`? Seriously. Run it in each project you're interested in deploying to Tomcat to generate the war file(s) - see below.

```
~/GWTP-Samples> find . -name *.war
./gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-mobile/target/gwtp-sample-mobile-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
./gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-basic/target/gwtp-sample-basic-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
./gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-basic-spring/target/gwtp-sample-basic-spring-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
./gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-crawler-service/target/gwtp-sample-crawler-service-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
./gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-nested/target/gwtp-sample-nested-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
./carstore/target/carstore-1.6-SNAPSHOT.war
./multimodule/aggregate/target/aggregate-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```